# How to avoid Visual Studio CTRL+SHIFT press down weary

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2013

I am tired of constantly having to keep pressing CTRL+SHIFT down when I am coding in visual studio (yes this means I do a lot of copy-pasting... that is how it is) and then using arrows to mark what I want to copy and then copy CTRL+C and use arrows and then paste CTRL+V. (actually I am weary of doing this in any editor)

I would like to avoid having to keep CTRL+SHIFT pressed down while marking what I am copying.

I was wondering if anybody knows how to or of an extensions that would allow you to for example press SHIFT,SHIFT quickly (meaning CTRL+SHIFT lock) and then when SHIFT,SHIFT is hit again the CTRL+SHIFT lock is lifted and the marked text is copied. That is, the work flow would be:

SHIFT, SHIFT (CTRL+SHIFT locked)
 
...using arrows...
SHIFT, SHIFT (CTRL+SHIFT unlocked and text copied)
...using arrows...
CTRL+V (paste)

In fact, it would be great to skip the CTRL+V also, this requires two hands and a lot of movement. Instead paste could be CTRL,CTRL.

I have no idea if this is utterly impossible due to how CTRL or SHIFT is handled etc.

Other suggestions are welcomed.

PS: A single SHIFT after CTRL+SHIFT locked might change to just SHIFT lock for better marking control.

Comment: You're looking for Windows' StickyKeys feature.

Comment: Probably should have said, this does not work exactly how I would like it, basically it also often just shuts off when doing any SHIFT+'key' so you have to start it again. But thanks.
Anyway, also considering a foot pedal instead...